# Update a df column based on a substring in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Afternoon All,

Looking to tweak this solution to return the correct `trading_book` based on a substring (first three characters) of the `ticker` passed:

```
def Get_Substring(string):
    if 'ACT' in string:
        return 'ZZZZGOVT'
    elif 'ACGB' in string:
        return 'ZZZZGOVT'
    elif 'NSW' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'TCV' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'SAFA' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'WATC' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'TAS' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'NTT' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'AUS' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    else:
        return ''non-inventory''

df = {
         'trading_book': ['non-inventory','non-inventory','non-inventory',
                          'non-inventory','non-inventory','non-inventory',
                          'non-inventory','non-inventory','non-inventory',
                          'non-inventory'
                            ],
         'ticker': ['ACTB 0 09/24/21','ACGB 2 1/4 11/21/22','NSWTC 3 04/20/29',
                    'TCV 1 1/2 09/10/31','SAFA 2 1/4 08/15/24','WATC 2 10/24/34',
                    'TASCOR 2 10/24/34','NTTC 2 10/24/34','AUSCAP 2 10/24/34',
                    'XXXX 5 DD/MM/YY'
                    ],

    }

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['trading_book','ticker'])
print(df)
df['trading_book'] = df.apply(lambda x: Get_Substring(df['ticker'].str.slice(0,3)))
print(df)
```

Output is returning NaN. Want solution to be:

```
trading_book ticker 
ZZZZGOVT    ACTB 0 09/24/21
ZZZZGOVT    ACGB 2 1/4 11/21/22
ZZZZSEMI    NSWTC 3 04/20/29
ZZZZSEMI    TCV 1 1/2 09/10/31
ZZZZSEMI    SAFA 2 1/4 08/15/24
ZZZZSEMI    WATC 2 10/24/34
ZZZZSEMI    TASCOR 2 10/24/34
ZZZZSEMI    NTTC 2 10/24/34
ZZZZSEMI    AUSCAP 2 10/24/34
non-inventory   XXXX 5 DD/MM/YY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, you can apply for `ticker` column only, like this :

```
import pandas as pd

def Get_Substring(string):
    if 'ACT' in string:
        return 'ZZZZGOVT'
    elif 'ACGB' in string:
        return 'ZZZZGOVT'
    elif 'NSW' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'TCV' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'SAFA' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'WATC' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'TAS' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'NTT' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    elif 'AUS' in string:
        return 'ZZZZSEMI'
    else:
        return 'non-inventory'

df = {
         'trading_book': ['non-inventory','non-inventory','non-inventory',
                          'non-inventory','non-inventory','non-inventory',
                          'non-inventory','non-inventory','non-inventory',
                          'non-inventory'
                            ],
         'ticker': ['ACTB 0 09/24/21','ACGB 2 1/4 11/21/22','NSWTC 3 04/20/29',
                    'TCV 1 1/2 09/10/31','SAFA 2 1/4 08/15/24','WATC 2 10/24/34',
                    'TASCOR 2 10/24/34','NTTC 2 10/24/34','AUSCAP 2 10/24/34',
                    'XXXX 5 DD/MM/YY'
                    ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['trading_book','ticker'])
print(df)
df['trading_book'] = df["ticker"].apply(lambda x: Get_Substring(x[0:4]))
print(df)
"""
    trading_book               ticker
0       ZZZZGOVT      ACTB 0 09/24/21
1       ZZZZGOVT  ACGB 2 1/4 11/21/22
2       ZZZZSEMI     NSWTC 3 04/20/29
3       ZZZZSEMI   TCV 1 1/2 09/10/31
4       ZZZZSEMI  SAFA 2 1/4 08/15/24
5       ZZZZSEMI      WATC 2 10/24/34
6       ZZZZSEMI    TASCOR 2 10/24/34
7       ZZZZSEMI      NTTC 2 10/24/34
8       ZZZZSEMI    AUSCAP 2 10/24/34
9  non-inventory      XXXX 5 DD/MM/YY
"""
```